# Удалить выбранный текст программно

Tags: c#

Как в textBox программно удалить выделенный текст? И как выделить весь текст тоже программно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [TextBoxBase.SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx)
- [TextBoxBase.SelectionLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionlength.aspx)
- [TextBoxBase.SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectedtext.aspx)

Все три свойства доступны для чтения и изменения. На страницах есть примеры использования.
Весь текст выделяется примерно так:

```
superTextBox2012.SelectionStart = 0;
superTextBox2012.SelectionLength = superTextBox2012.TextLength;
```

Или так:

```
superTextBox2012.SelectAll();
```